# The query argument must have a placeholder

Tags: sql, wordpress

where am I doing in this query?

```
$sql=$wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE `meta_key`='_favorites' AND `post_id` = '$post_id'");
```

Comment: you repplace $post_id

Answer (score 0):

Placeholders are used to replace variables.
What I don't get, why you had `$post_id` in single quotes, they aren't needed for numbers

so use

```php
$sql=$wpdb->prepare( "SELECT * FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE `meta_key` = '_favorites' AND `post_id` = %d", $post_id );
```